# AngularJS NgMap displayed wrong marker position by city name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I trying to place simple marker according [this example](https://ngmap.github.io/#/!marker_with_dynamic_address.html) but all works only with static city f.e. "Toronto". In case of dynamic cities names the marker placed in center of the world map.

Here is my code:

```
<div map-lazy-load="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js">
       <ng-map zoom="11" center="{{vm.city}}">
            <marker position="{{vm.city}}"
                title="You are here"
                centered="true"
            ></marker>
       </ng-map>
</div>
```

[image: dynamic city name]

**What I'm doing wrong ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior  if geographic coordinates (lat,lng) for marker position  could not be properly determined.

When the *address* is specified for marker position, [Geocoding Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) is utilized behind the scene to resolve the `lat,lng`. In your case most likely `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` [status code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingStatusCodes) is getting returned since [Geocoding API usage limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing) has been exceeded.

There are might be another reasons why address could not be resolved via Geocoding API, but basically if status code return any value which differs from `"OK"`, marker is getting displayed in position `{lat:0,lng:0}`